# hours.minutes sexagesimal SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with 2 columns, Hours and TotalHours, both numeric(5,2), and I want to make the SUM of all rows.

As you can see in the image below, the difference between the columns is that, the first column contains minutes in sexagesimal format, while the second column contains minutes in centesimal format `(minutes : 60 = x : 100)`.

[image: hours and minutes sum]

Independently of the column, and of the format, I'm using, how can I get the SUM of all the rows in **sexagesimal** format ?

Note:
 
1) I'm using SQL SERVER 2008.
2) I have to use numeric(5,2) format as INPUT for both columns.

Comment: SUM the centesimal values and convert to sexagesimal when done.

Comment: BTW, never store the same value in two different columns just based on format. Store only once and convert when read (perhaps using a view.) To avoid data inconsistency!

Comment: Thank you for observations, they were very helpful !

For those who use the first road, Do you know, if there's a solution that exclude the cast of the row before sum ? (from sexagesimal to centesimal for each record, and inversely on the sum ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your data you could shortcut this by summing the decimal column and converting the result to sexagesimal format

select cast(12.71 as int) + (12.71 - cast(12.71 as int)) * 60/100

Or you could convert the sexagesimal format column to decimal and sum like this

```
select Sum(cast(12.43 as int) + (12.43 - cast(12.43 as int)) * 100/60.00)
```

And then apply the above to convert it back to sexagesimal format

Answer (score 0):

```
-- As suggested by jarlh and by user3540780 I resolved with this:

DECLARE @Hours as Table(
    TotalHours numeric(5,2)
)

INSERT INTO @Hours VALUES(12.81)
INSERT INTO @Hours VALUES(3.71)
INSERT INTO @Hours VALUES(11.12)
INSERT INTO @Hours VALUES(1.01)
INSERT INTO @Hours VALUES(6.30)
INSERT INTO @Hours VALUES(9.88)
INSERT INTO @Hours VALUES(10.91)
INSERT INTO @Hours VALUES(9.88)
INSERT INTO @Hours VALUES(0.28)

SELECT CAST(SUM((CAST(TotalHours as int)) + ((TotalHours - CAST(TotalHours as int)) * 60/100)) as numeric(5,2)) as SumSexagesimalHours
FROM @Hours
```